# django tutorial no module named staticfilespolls error

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-settings, django-staticfiles

I had previously done the first part of the tutorial, got stuck, realized there were several versions of the tutorial, deleted the polls and mysite directories and started again. However, when I run

$ python manage.py sql polls
the result is:

```
     c:\Python27\Scripts\mysite>python manage.py sql polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 280,
 in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", lin
e 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", l
ine 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named staticfilespolls
```

In settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    'polls',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where the error is coming from.

Comment: need a comma after `'django.contrib.staticfiles'`

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a comma after the `django.contrib.staticfiles` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',  # HERE
    'polls',
)
```

Without a comma, python interprets `django.contrib.staticfiles` and `polls` strings as a single one.

Demo:

```
>>> s = ('what', 
...      'a',
...      'wonderful'
...      'world')
>>> s
('what', 'a', 'wonderfulworld')

>>> s = ('what',
...      'a',
...      'wonderful',
...      'world')
>>> s
('what', 'a', 'wonderful', 'world')
```